# ddrescue to the same disk

Tags: ddrescue

`ddrescue` will complain if the source device is the same as the destination device:

```
ddrescue: Infile and outfile are the same.
```

Even `-f` cannot convince `ddrescue` to do what I mean.

How can I trick `ddrescue` to write to the same device?

Comment: I’m curious what the use case is here...

Comment: Use `--same-file`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loopback device:

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop3 /dev/sdf
sudo ddrescue -f /dev/sdf /dev/loop3 my.log
```